# Why there's no %ebp register in gdb?

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers

```
(gdb) info registers %ebp 
Invalid register `%ebp'
```

Isn't `%ebp` register available in all platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is info registers $ebp

It works for me

Comment: @compile-fan http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/idb/olh/commands104.html

Answer (score 1):

It's `info registers ebp` not `%ebp`. But no, you can't assume every platform has a specific register.

Comment: `info registers ebp` doesn't work either,`Invalid register ebp`

Comment: @assem: Then your platform doesn't have ebp. Try simply `info registers`

Comment: @assem: Find an instruction set reference for your CPU - gdb just provides the tools, you'll need to learn what's required to utilize it.

Comment: @Erik,seems not,`rbp` also works for me on `Intel(R) Xeon(TM)`

Comment: @compile-fan: RBP is the EBP equivalent for x86-64, which was originally called amd64. intel64 is more or less a straight copy of the amd64 instruction set - xeon 64-bit mode will have the same register